# Connecting Bluetooth in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I have done a simple app to connect my phone with an Arduino via BT and all goes right. My phone have Android 2.3.6... But, when I try the app on my tablet (with android 4.0.3), I can't connect. I post here the specific piece of code:

```
try {
        BluetoothSocket socket = mydevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(ARDUINO_STANDAR_UUID));
        socket.connect();
        OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
        InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
        Log.d(TAG, "Connected");
    }
    catch (IOException e) { Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage()); }
}
```

Using the Log, the problem is at socket.connect(); at that point, I have to enter the PIN of the device, but it don't connect anyway... The error is "Connection refused"...

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this to take care of the connection. I just updated an old android-10 app the other day to android-17 and dealt with exactly this.

```
BluetoothDevice yourDevice;
try {
        Method m = yourDevice.getClass().getMethod( "createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class } );
        selectedDeviceSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke( yourDevice, Integer.valueOf( 1 ) );
        selectedDeviceSocket.connect();
    }
```

Comment: What it preferredDevice?

Comment: Sorry about that, it's just yourDevice.  I changed names for some reason.

Comment: Oh! I have to make you a present!!!! You have solved my problem!!! Many many thanks! =) =)

Comment: No problem!  Glad I could help a fellow Android / Arduinoer